# Primefaces - how to display dataGrid and select menu inline

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

It may sound a silly question but I've tried everything: with style attribute (display: inline), with styleClass attribute but nothing.
I want this code to be displayed on the same line/row:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{not empty enastrSearch.recordsList}">
                <p:dataTable id="tableData" var="record" value="#{enastrSearch.recordsList}" style="border: 0px" >
                    <p:column>
                        <p:dataGrid var="column" value="#{record.renderColumnList}" columns="4" style="display: inline">
                            <p:column>
                                #{column.columnValue}
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{options.selectedBank}" style="display: inline" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{banks.currentBanks}"  />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add the following to your CSS:

```css
#tableData .ui-datagrid { 
    float: left;
}
```

*Or* if that doesn't achieve the desired layout (the items will collapse together without whitespace, you'd need to manipulate the whitespace yourself inside the datagrid's column content), then put them in a `<h:panelGrid columns="2">` instead:

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:dataGrid ... />
    <h:selectOneMenu ... />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: How could I put a header row with every column name? If I put it inside the dataGrid, the name of the column appears for every each row, and I don't want that; if i put it above the dataTable, the names aren't formatted in the way column values appears.